# Are node.js APIs effective with parameter reference, or only good with return values?

Tags: node.js

Are node.js APIs effective with parameter reference, or only good with return values?

For example, will `myPath` get normalized if I do this:

```
var path = require('path'),
    myPath = "my/path";
    path.normalize(myPath);
```

Or will it only work this way:

```
    myPath = path.normalize("my/path");
```

I'm just curious.

**EDIT:** Fantastic and concise explanation here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3638034/1049693

Comment: I don't understand the close votes - do people even read my question? It is not about which is better - it's about if it is technically possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, didn't read your question right the first time.

NodeJS is a JavaScript engine with a bunch of libraries and an event loop. More specifically NodeJS uses the same JavaScript engine as Google Chrome (V8).

In JavaScript strings are [primitive value](http://es5.github.io/#x8) types and [moreover are immutable](http://es5.github.io/#x8.4) (as value types generally are). You are therefor [passing a value](http://es5.github.io/#x13.2.1) and not a reference. It is impossible to change the value of a string inside a function in JavaScript.

```
var a = "Some String";
myFunction(a);
console.log(a);// We can know for sure that `a` is still "Some String"*
```

If this is still unclear you might want to check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/518000/1348195) about how JavaScript passes variables around.

<sup>* Unless myFunction is defined in the same closure or has explicit access to the variable itself, even in such case, the string `a` itself did not change.</sup>

Comment: Oh yes, primitive values! I even remember reading the exact question you linked. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Go with the second one, as the first will not change the value of myPath, but rather return an new string that has been normalized.  Or as another options

```
myPath = "my/path";
myPath = path.normalize(myPath);
```

I like this one only because it adds a little flexibility.  Say later you want to do more with myPath *prior to* normalizing it.  You can then leave the line doing the normalizing alone and add additional logic above. Mostly I'm just a fan of doing string assignments at the top of my function if possible...